# Storing reporting assemblies (.net) in a database

Tags: c#, database, assemblies, compilation

I'm developing a project where users need to build reporting queries using complex Linq statements to generate data sets.

The best way I could think of to compile these user-generated queries and then execute them is to use the CSharpCodeProvider object to build an assembly and then store the result in a database blob.

Is there anything wrong with this process? Also, how can I restrict the permissions of the user assembly to only allow execution against a limited set of objects that I provide?

Thanks!

Comment: are you building a reporting engine by any chance?

Comment: Yes, but based on Linq rather than SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to save the queries as a generated assembly.  A simpler way would be to save the SQL executed against the database for future use.  Use the [GetCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) method of the DataContext to get the SQL and persist it as a "saved" query.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but this is a really good idea. In this case it would be eSQL since I'm running against the EF but I'm going to revisit this later and I might decide to go with it.

Comment: Actually with EF it's still SQL that gets executed agains the SQL db.  eSQL is used to query Entities.